# How can I fix this Django HTML template bug?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have this weird bug with Django HTML templates, that everything seems to be placed inside the body nomatter what I do. Additionally it adds some invisible text that gives the whole page a little offset.

[How my browser displays the Sourcecode when I inspect the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKvHr.png)

[How the pages sourcecode looks when I open it inside the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2ALH.png)

The second image is how it is supposed to look like.

This is how my actual code looks like:

base.html:

```html
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

home.html:

```html
﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Name</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Text</p>
    </body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

This only happens when I use inheritance. When I put alle the code in one .html file it gets displayed as it should.

I've tried to move the block part and for example but the everything but the paragraph inside the base.html file but it didn't change anything.

I hope someone can help me.

This is my first post stackoverflow btw, so please be kind.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't seem to provide enough information for me but from what I can see the problem lies in:

1. Loading static
2. And your block content

so your code should be something like

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Name</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<p>Text</p>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both and neither did work.

Comment: I think I know why it didn't help:

1. loading static probably didn't help since there are no static element inside my code.
2. The Django HTML template inheritance works in a way, that your derived file copies the super file and only the code inside the blocks gets overwritten.

I don't exactly know which other information i can provide. 
I'm working with a standard Visual Studio Community 19 generated Django Project and didn't alter much else than adding a new app and the urls.py and view.py files.

Comment: changing position of block content ain't working too?

Comment: nope. it's like there is an invisible  fixed elemtent with top: 0; element above everything else.